# CSS/HTML - Flexbox - Center responsive elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to implement a responsive page. I've managed to get the following result, but I wish all the boxes (logo|links|ic|breadcrumb) to be full height/width of their parents. These boxes should also fill fully the available space.

[image]

## Fiddle links

- with `min-height` : https://jsfiddle.net/sxr3eq84/142/
- with `align-items: stretch` on parents : https://jsfiddle.net/ycsmo8fx/15/

## What I've tried

- forced `<nav><a/><nav>` from header to take the full space using `min-height` property but it breaks Flexbox `align-items: center;` property.

## Desired output

- all my Flexbox children look like the top left blue box without breaking `align-items: center;` property.
- all `<nav><a/></nav>` from header both centered vertically and horizontally while taking the whole available free space.
- breadcrumb items both centered vertically and horizontally while taking the whole available free space.

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-wrap: break-work;
  }

.root {
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.header {
  /* FLEX */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
  /* OTHERS PROPS */
  height: 80px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  
  /* set a solid border inside the header and not on its edge */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

.header-child-1 {
  /* FLEX */
  flex: 3;
  
  /* OTHERS PROPS */
  min-height: 80px; /* ERROR : using min-height property breaks align-items */
  background-color: blue;
}

.header-child-2 {
  /* FLEX */
  flex: 5;
  
  /* OTHERS PROPS */
  background-color: white;
}

.header-child-3 {
  /* FLEX */
  flex: 3;
  
  /* OTHERS PROPS */
  background-color: red;
}

.main {
  /* FLEX */
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  /* OTHERS PROPS */
  height: calc(100vh - 80px);
  background-color: green;
}

.main-header {
  /* FLEX */
  flex: 1;
  
  /* OTHERS PROPS */
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 40px;
  max-height: 40px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.main-main {
  /* FLEX */
  flex: 1;
  
  /* REMOVE THE GLOBAL PAGE SCROLLBAR, FLEXBOX ADD IT AUTOMATICALLY TO THAT HTML ELEMENT */
  overflow: auto;
  
  /* OTHERS PROPS */
  text-align: justify;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='root'>
      <header class='header'>
        <nav class='header-child-1'>
          <a>Logo</a>
        </nav>
        <nav class='header-child-2'>
          <a>link1</a>
          <a>link2</a>
          <a>link3</a>
        </nav>
        <nav class='header-child-3'>
          <a>ic1</a>
          <a>ic2</a>
          <a>ic3</a>
        </nav>
      </header>

      <main class='main'>
        <header class='main-header'>
          <a>Breadcrumb 1</a>
          <a>Breadcrumb 2</a>
        </header>

        <main class='main-main'>
        content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
        </main>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want your code to do? We can't help you fix a problem if you don't tell us what it is :)

Comment: What did you understood from the last paragraph 'Desired output' so I can edit my question to be more precise ? :)

Comment: It looks like the options in your example are already centered and fill the space, so what specifically is it that you are trying to change? For example, is the problem that the container doesn't fill the screen on large screens - is the this available space you want to use? Or do you want them spaced *evenly* across the allocated space?

Comment: The white and red boxes don't fill the vertical space.
Indeed I want to spaced them evenly across the allocated space.

Comment: Your question says that you are *trying to implement the page shown in the image*, which is exactly what your code is creating. If that isn't the page you actually want to create, then you should update your question to show us what you *are* looking for - otherwise it looks like you have already achieved what you said you wanted.

Comment: You're totally right. I've edited my message, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.header{
align-items: stretch;
}

.header-child-1, .header-child-2, .header-child-3{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
//remove min-height from .header-child-1
}
    
.header-child-2{
display: flex;
}

.header-child-2 a{
width: 33.333%;
}

.main-header{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

.main-header a{
width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Not what I'm looking for.

Comment: scratch what you are looking for on paper or image.

Comment: A mix of the two Fiddle links : full sized boxes with centered content (i.e. links)

Comment: Work like a charm ! 
However It makes all header-child-x both container and item at the same time. Is that a good practice ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try display:flex for all wrappers, where you need horizontally and vertically center align.**

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-wrap: break-work;
  }

.root {
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.header {
  /* FLEX */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
  /* OTHERS PROPS */
  height: 80px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  
  /* set a solid border inside the header and not on its edge */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

.header-child-1 {
  /* FLEX */
  display: flex;
  flex:3;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  /* OTHERS PROPS */
  min-height: 80px; /* ERROR : using min-height property breaks align-items */
  background-color: blue;
}

.header-child-2 {
  /* FLEX */
  flex: 5;
  
  /* OTHERS PROPS */
  background-color: white;
}

.header-child-3 {
  /* FLEX */
  flex: 3;
  
  /* OTHERS PROPS */
  background-color: red;
}

.main {
  /* FLEX */
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  /* OTHERS PROPS */
  height: calc(100vh - 80px);
  background-color: green;
}

.main-header {
  /* FLEX */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  /* OTHERS PROPS */
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 40px;
  max-height: 40px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.main-main {
  /* FLEX */
  flex: 1;
  
  /* REMOVE THE GLOBAL PAGE SCROLLBAR, FLEXBOX ADD IT AUTOMATICALLY TO THAT HTML ELEMENT */
  overflow: auto;
  
  /* OTHERS PROPS */
  text-align: justify;
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="root">
      <header class="header">
        <nav class="header-child-1"><a>Logo</a></nav>
        <nav class="header-child-2"><a>link1</a> <a>link2</a> <a>link3</a></nav>
        <nav class="header-child-3"><a>ic1</a> <a>ic2</a> <a>ic3</a></nav>
      </header>

      <main class="main">
        <header class="main-header">
          <a>Breadcrumb 1</a> <a>Breadcrumb 2</a>
        </header>

        <main class="main-main">
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content
        </main>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```